# How to make a program that accepts words that either start with a lowercase or uppercase letter java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm just messing around in java and want to make a true or false trivia, what would be the best way to make the program accept the users input whether it starts with a lowercase or uppercase letter? (e.g. a true or false statement, that will accept either "True/false" or "true/false"). I tried looking on google but I can't find anything because I don't really know how to word it correctly.

Comment: "string functions" i.e. methods of the class [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), terminal I/O, especially Scanner, and simple control statements

Answer (score 3):

I would do

```
String input = 
if (input.equalsCaseIgnore("true")) // match any case combination of TrUe or trUE
```

If you are using a switch statement you can't do this but you can do

```
switch(input.toLowerCase()) {
   case "true": // true in any case
       break;
   case "false": // false in any case
       break;
   default:
       // handle error
       break;
}
```

Comment: Interesting I only thought that the case in the switch statement only could have numbers. But I think I'll use the first one thanks for the help :)

Comment: As of Java 7 you can switch on Strings too, so be mindful of your Java version. I am pretty much anti-switch though haha.

Comment: Lol, I will be mindful with it, other than that most the things I am seeing is pretty easy. And I find the switch statements simple when it comes to "press a # that corresponds to the following..."

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
    System.out.println("You input " + input);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Input is invalid");
}
```